# Add object to ObservableArray

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have an data object which is dynamic as it was read from a WebApi Load Data call... and then converted into an observable using:

```
 $.get("/api/PlateTemplate/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Data);  
            self.IsDataLoaded(true);
        });
```

One of the fields is an observable array of another object type. I use this to render some tabs on my UI.

```
<div id="plateTemplate" data-bind="with: Data">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: PlateTemplateGroups">
                <li data-bind="css: {active: $index()==0}"><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: {href: ('#tabId' + $index())}"><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This works. All good. I have a button which I would like to use to add a new tabl. I allow the user to type in a name, and then click the button. I want to add a new tab. So, I attempt to add a new item to my Data object:

But first, to check that my tab group is 'observed', I just hardcode a name change to the first tab:

```
self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups()[0].Description("hahahaha");
```

And as that executes, the first tabs display name changes. Also, when I post my self.Data() back to my controller, the changes are reflected.

Then I try to add a new item:

```
self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups().push({ Id: ko.observable(0), Description: ko.observable(name), Components: ko.observableArray([]) });
```

This executes, but no new tab appears.

However, when I post my model back to my .Net controller, I see the new item.

[image]

Is there any reason why the new tab never appears? Maybe I am adding to the obervableArray incorrectly? I'm worried why I need to reference the objects using () all the time as well.

Comment: You need to push directly to the observable, not to the array it returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewModel you have an observable property `Data`.  This property has other properties, like an observable array called `PlateTemplateGroups`.

Because `Data` is an observable that contains an object, you need to call it as a function to get this object:

```
Data()
```

Now, you can  add an element to `PlateTemplateGroups` with `push()`:

```
 self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups.push( ... )
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQgwGb) as example.  You can click the button and a `TemplateGroup` is added.

Comment: Wow... perfect! Thanks! That resolved it. I'm battling to understand when to use () and when not to. Maybe is a context issue I'm not understanding, but your fix has worked. Thank you.